# Laravel クエリビルド SQL バインド変数？の明示方法はありますか？

Tags: laravel

```
ListArray = [1,2,3];
Stack::where('columnA',$ListArray)->toSQL;
```

としてSQLの中身を確認したところ、`` where (`columnA` = ?) `` と表示されていました。

ちゃんと配列の要素分 `where` が効いているのか確認したいのですが良い方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

下記のような感じで「`toSql`」ではなくて、「`getBindings`」を使うと、バインドした内容を確認することができるかと思います。
あと、コードの転記ミスかもしれないんですが、「`ListArray`」の前の「`$`」が抜けているようです。

```
$ListArray = [1,2,3];
Stack::where('columnA',$ListArray)->getBindings();
```